# Is it possible to recover data from Intel RAID 0 drives on an AMD system?

Tags: linux, raid

I am running an AMD system and I have a problem where I cannot recover files from two former Intel RAID 0 drives.

```
Disk /dev/sde: 111.8 GiB, 120034123776 bytes, 234441648 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/sdf: 111.8 GiB, 120034123776 bytes, 234441648 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x373c74a7
```

I've spent a rather long time trying to figure out how I can mount these drives, as I would like to copy the data from them, which brought me to use `mdadm`:

```
$ sudo mdadm --assemble /dev/md0 /dev/sdf1 /dev/sde --force
mdadm: only give one device per ARRAY line: /dev/md/Main and SystemFS
mdadm: no recogniseable superblock on /dev/sdf1
mdadm: /dev/sdf1 has no superblock - assembly aborted
```

The errors I am receiving are rather confusing because I do know for sure the drives in question are functional, but for one reason or another they don't seem to want to play nice with `mdadm` - how can I fix this?

There does not seem to be useful information on this topic applicable to this context.

Comment: Please update link with a non-cloud share link _(current link is broken)_, preferably a permanent web link as this post will be around for over a decade.

Comment: Are those Google drive images necessary? Or do they just repeat what you have posted already? The reason I ask is the link you provided is clearly not going to work: `https://drive.google.com/drive/folde...gq?usp=sharing` Those ellipsis (`...`) are clearly not a part of the URL.

Comment: My apologies this issue has been somewhat frustrating

Comment: Additionally there is no prospect of advice being given on this topic regardless. So the picture links are somewhat redundant unless someone would consider proving me wrong.

Comment: Raid O has no redundancy, so it is near impossible to do it yourself, but can be done by recovery companies at high expense.

Comment: I don't think you understand my question the drives and the data on them is intact. The problem is mounting these drives to linux